# Pasting via vim doesn't paste whole text and gets stuck in the insert paste mode

Tags: terminal, cut-copy-paste, macvim, macos, paste

For a while now, I've been dealing with a problem where when pasting a large amount of text, such as the code in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/StrangeRanger/b848d8eeef31dae1cebc9a68ac10df35), into a file via vim, only part of the copied text gets pasted, then stops and gets stuck in "insert paste" mode. Why trying to press `esc` on my computer, `^[` gets printed into the file. I find that the only way to get out of the "insert paste" mode is by using `Ctrl` + `C`.
https://asciinema.org/a/nhDJfd1P8g7c2j1XgaJ8KCU7X

I've tried using `vim --clean filename`, and it ends with the same result.
https://asciinema.org/a/60qpQsHIqegLdd3F9HdntNkRw

I've seen a few other questions similar to the predicament that I'm in, but all answers suggest that it's possible that `Ctrl` + `S` was accidentally pressed during pasting, but this just isn't the case for me. I've never accidentally or purposefully pressed that key combination.

One thing I think might be important to note, is that this problem doesn't occur when using macvim. It only happens when using vim via the terminal. Additionally, I find that when I use tmux and then perform vim, as long as I use `:set paste` to allow for proper spacing, I have no problem pasting the entire piece of text.
https://asciinema.org/a/a1Wya4OfqOfsllotrtkmTenaM

Here is the output of `vim --version`:

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 9.0 (2022 Jun 28, compiled Aug 28 2022 16:44:20)
macOS version - x86_64
Included patches: 1-300
Compiled by Homebrew
Huge version without GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
+acl               +file_in_path      +mouse_urxvt       -tag_any_white
+arabic            +find_in_path      +mouse_xterm       -tcl
+autocmd           +float             +multi_byte        +termguicolors
+autochdir         +folding           +multi_lang        +terminal
-autoservername    -footer            -mzscheme          +terminfo
-balloon_eval      +fork()            +netbeans_intg     +termresponse
+balloon_eval_term +gettext           +num64             +textobjects
-browse            -hangul_input      +packages          +textprop
++builtin_terms    +iconv             +path_extra        +timers
+byte_offset       +insert_expand     +perl              +title
+channel           +ipv6              +persistent_undo   -toolbar
+cindent           +job               +popupwin          +user_commands
-clientserver      +jumplist          +postscript        +vartabs
+clipboard         +keymap            +printer           +vertsplit
+cmdline_compl     +lambda            +profile           +vim9script
+cmdline_hist      +langmap           -python            +viminfo
+cmdline_info      +libcall           +python3           +virtualedit
+comments          +linebreak         +quickfix          +visual
+conceal           +lispindent        +reltime           +visualextra
+cryptv            +listcmds          +rightleft         +vreplace
+cscope            +localmap          +ruby              +wildignore
+cursorbind        +lua               +scrollbind        +wildmenu
+cursorshape       +menu              +signs             +windows
+dialog_con        +mksession         +smartindent       +writebackup
+diff              +modify_fname      -sodium            -X11
+digraphs          +mouse             -sound             -xfontset
-dnd               -mouseshape        +spell             -xim
-ebcdic            +mouse_dec         +startuptime       -xpm
+emacs_tags        -mouse_gpm         +statusline        -xsmp
+eval              -mouse_jsbterm     -sun_workshop      -xterm_clipboard
+ex_extra          +mouse_netterm     +syntax            -xterm_save
+extra_search      +mouse_sgr         +tag_binary        
-farsi             -mouse_sysmouse    -tag_old_static    
   system vimrc file: "$VIM/vimrc"
     user vimrc file: "$HOME/.vimrc"
 2nd user vimrc file: "~/.vim/vimrc"
      user exrc file: "$HOME/.exrc"
       defaults file: "$VIMRUNTIME/defaults.vim"
  fall-back for $VIM: "/usr/local/share/vim"
Compilation: clang -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DMACOS_X -DMACOS_X_DARWIN -g -O2 -D_REENTRANT -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1 
Linking: clang -L. -fstack-protector-strong -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/opt/libyaml/lib -L/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib -L/usr/local/lib -o vim -lm -lncurses -liconv -lintl -framework AppKit -L/usr/local/opt/lua/lib -llua5.4 -mmacosx-version-min=12.0 -fstack-protector-strong -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/Cellar/perl/5.34.0/lib/perl5/5.34.0/darwin-thread-multi-2level/CORE -lperl -L/usr/local/opt/python@3.10/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/config-3.10-darwin -lpython3.10 -framework CoreFoundation -lruby.3.1 -L/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/3.1.2_1/lib
```

Comment: Even if you didn't press `<c-s>` yourself, what you paste may contain this sequence, or others. I think that's the potential problem depicted by the answers you read. You could try `:set paste` before actually pasting.

Comment: @Biggybi Oh, ok. Though `:set paste` has no affect on anything, unless I'm using tmux + vim, to ensure proper spacing and alignment.

Comment: Welcome to Vim :-) could you tell us what happens when you copy and past a similar gist but without lines from 35 to 40? What happens when you copy and past a similar gist but without line 42? I would to know if it past more? Is the size of the past dependent of the size or from the content?

Comment: @VivianDeSmedt If I remove the code from lines 35-40 and line 42 (in two separate instances respectively), it still only prints down to line 42. I tried it with a different script, specifically [this one](https://github.com/StrangeRanger/mass-git/blob/main/mass-git), and it only prints down to line 34.

Comment: It feels like your problems come from your terminal settings. You could try different emulators (i.e. iTerm) and see how it goes.